# Unique Values Excel Column, no missing info in rows - Python

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, multiple-columns

Currently self-teaching Python and running into some issues. My challenge requires me to count the number of unique values in a column of an excel spreadsheet in which the rows have no missing values. Here is what I've got so far but I can't seem to get it to work:

```
import xlrd

import pandas as pd

workbook = xlrd.open_workbook("*name of excel spreadsheet*")

worksheet = workbook.sheet_by_name("*name of specific sheet*")

pd.value_counts(df.*name of specific column*)

s = pd.value_counts(df.*name of specific column*)

s1 = pd.Series({'nunique': len(s), 'unique values': s.index.tolist()})

s.append(s1)

print(s)
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the built in to find the unique in the columns:

sharing an example with you:

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame(columns=["a","b"])
df["a"]=[1,3,3,3,4]
df["b"]=[1,2,2,3,4]
print(df["a"].unique())
```

will give the following result:

```
[1 3 4]
```

So u can store it as a list to a variable if you like, with:

```
l_of_unique_vals=df["a"].unique()
```

and find its length or do anything as you like

```
df = pd.read_excel("nameoffile.xlsx", sheet_name=name_of_sheet_you_are_loading) 
#in the line above we are reading the file in a pandas dataframe and giving it a name df 
df["column you want to find vals from"].unique()
```

Comment: thank you for your comment. In this example, how would I define my excel column as df? In your example, you are reating the dataframe right in the module.

Comment: you can open your excel in a pandas dataframe. lemme demonstrate that in my answer, editing it to include your questions code

Comment: @BenSmert the name of the columns will be as they are in exel file but if you wish to look at the data and columns you can always print it with `print(df)`

Answer (score -1):

First you can use *Pandas* `read_exel` and then `unique` such as @Inder suggested.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_exel('name_of_your_file.xlsx')
print(df['columns'].unique())
```

See more [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_excel.html).